# Can I use a higher-Amperage charger (3.95 vs 3.42) with my Toshiba laptop?

Tags: toshiba-laptop, charger

The adapter is 'Toshiba', but the laptop specifies a 19v, 3.42 amp connection.

Would using a 19v **3.95** amp adapter in my Toshiba laptop cause any ill effects?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the connector and polarity match, being able to supply more current than required is not a problem.